# Error on running react-native run-android: "Unable to load script"

Tags: react-native

I did a first project on react-native, that still works when I want to emulate it on my AVD.
I started a react-native init new project that installed correctly but impossible to run it the first time, Node JS command open and shut down in a seconde. And, come to this point :

```
"Starting: Intent { cmp=com.ms/.MainActivity }"
```

Nothing happens : the following line is this one : `PS C:\Users\arthu\MS>`

And I get the error message : "Unable to load script. Make sure you either running a metro server (run react-native' start) or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged correctly for release.

Thought it was due to the Node JS console, which was opening a few second, so I emptied its cache, didn't change anything, Re-installing Node JS, re-tried with my ancient project (which works), change port from where I run the project, nothing changed.

I guess it is not linked with Node JS, neither my code (because I didn't even start), but I am a bit confused about that, and didn't find a similar post ! Thank you for your answers ;)

Comment: Check this https://medium.com/@adityasingh_32512/solved-unable-to-load-script-from-assets-index-android-bundle-bdc5e3a3d5ff this might solve your problem too.

Comment: Hi ! Thank you for the answer ! :)
I tried this, but got this exact same error